# multicolor subitem in listview - is it possible?

Tags: c#, listview

Straight to the question: Is it possible to insert a string in a subitem which each leter has a different color???

I would like to represent time delay using colors. Example:
Subitem string "10 14 50" and values 10 and 50 with color red and 14 with green.

Comment: Not directly. But there are usercontrols readily available, like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

Comment: Thank you @DanByström i'll keep your suggestion in mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the OwnerDraw mode to true and supply the drawing routine yourself:

```
listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
listView1.DrawColumnHeader += listView1_DrawColumnHeader;
listView1.DrawSubItem += listView1_DrawSubItem;

void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e) {
  e.DrawDefault = true;
}

void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
    e.Graphics.SetClip(e.Bounds);
    using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(listView1.BackColor)) {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);
    }
    int textLeft = e.Bounds.Left;
    string[] subItems = e.Item.SubItems[1].Text.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < subItems.Length; ++i) {
      int textWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(subItems[i], listView1.Font).Width;
      TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, subItems[i], listView1.Font,
          new Rectangle(textLeft, e.Bounds.Top, textWidth, e.Bounds.Height),
          i == 0 ? Color.Red : i == subItems.Length - 1 ? Color.Green : Color.Black, 
          Color.Empty,
          TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping);
      textLeft += textWidth;
    }
    e.Graphics.ResetClip();
  } else {
    e.DrawDefault = true;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]